# Can a bike computer be used on the rear wheel?

Tags: road-bike, trainer, bike-computer

As the weather gets colder and colder, I find myself on a trainer more and more. The only way to gauge my workouts is by time, unless I set up the sensor for my bike computer on my rear wheel.

[image: Bike Computer On Rear Wheel]

Will the computer work accurately on the rear wheel? Are there any disadvantages having it on the rear wheel?

Comment: Depends on the computer.  Some are wired and only have a short wire to reach down the fork.  And some wireless models do not have enough "range" to receive from a sensor mounted on the rear.  But, if you can get it to work, it should be just as accurate on the rear as on the front.

Comment: @DanielRHicks You could mount it to the seat post rather than the handlebars, if you don't need to look at it during the workout. Or set up a camera to look at it

Comment: @DanielRHicks, All the wired bike computers I've seen have been simple 2-core wires.  They could be extended (for indoor use) without even soldering, by using terminal blocks and a bit of bell wire.

Comment: +1 for the rear light so you can still train safely at night, even in a power cut.

Comment: If you have a dedicated bike for the trainer, then permanently move the sensor.  Or even buy a second cheap wired bike computer and fit it for winter training and remove again when the weather improves.  Doesn't need to be particularly flash computer - $10 or $20 would get you something useful.

Comment: Your other option is to apply rule 9 http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#9 followed by rule 5 http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#5

Comment: @Random832 - Yeah, or maybe mount it on the top tube so you can see it and operate the buttons between your legs.

Comment: As long as you're not slamming the brakes every now and then, the backwheel should be fine ;)

Comment: @wullxz why would brakes be relevant?  The sensor would have to cope with braking of the front wheel when in normal use.  Are you concerned the spoke magnet will come loose?   Depending on the trainer, it might take a while to wind down, so braking the wheel to a stop is a good idea before dismounting.

Comment: Good to see you've started on the review queues! There's some material on meta that may be of use: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/1028/8273

Comment: @DavidRicherby The rear light for safety was an afterthought. My main concern is that I'm no longer aero, because my computer is on my top tube.

Comment: @andy256 Thanks, I just read it and will keep that in mind the next time I go to review.

Comment: @Criggie I'm not a native speaker and don't know how to say it correctly. What I meant is: if he slams the brakes so that his backwheel doesn't turn anymore, his speedometer won't measure anything anymore.

Comment: @wullxz so when the bike "stops" the speedo stops too?  I see no problem with that.

Comment: @Criggie the bike doesn't stop if he's sliding. The frontwheel spins, the backwheel blocks.

Comment: @wullxz the photo shows it is a rear-wheel-only resistance trainer, not a set of rollers.  The front wheel does not spin at all, which is why OP wants to move the computer sensor to the rear wheel.

Comment: @Criggie the photo also shows, that this is a real bike. I don't think he's going to move the sensor to the front wheel every time he's using his bike outside. I guess after a discussion like this, my comment above won't become funnier. Just drop it, you missed the point.

Answer (score 12):

Totally fine - its a good idea.  You'll need to move the sensor and fit a second spoke magnet (or move your front wheel one)

Another option would be fit an ant+ or bluetooth sensor and look at virtual ride tools like zwift, but they're not free.

Another option is count your pedal strokes and aim for 90 every minute, but that gets boring.

Comment: Why aim for 90? People seem to think that one's natural cadence is probably best, unless it's unusually fast or slow. In terms of measuring distance "travelled", you just need to know your cadence and gearing.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Fair point.  Aim for "the cadence you would normally use on the road" for consistency.  Or add 5 or 10 to that if you want to pick up the pace.  Indoor training lacks a lot of realism, so working slightly harder when indoors helps to redress that difference.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can, although my suggestion is buying another cycle computer rather than trying to re-fit an existing cycle computer as you appear to be asking for.

I've always used a cadence cycle computer. The [Cateye Strada](http://www.cateye.com/intl/products/detail/CC-RD200/) wired cycle computer connects to the crank arm and the rear wheel.

Then you have cadence as well as speed and you can put the computer back on your handle bars.

From the [manual](http://cateye.com/images/manual/CC-RD200_ENG%20v6.pdf):

[image]

Comment: @DavidRicherby the question was 'Can a bike computer be used on the rear wheel?', I took that to mean any bike computer, not just ones that are designed for the front wheel. Perhaps the question could be changed to be more precised, but for people searching for this question in the future I think my answer is a reasonable one.

Comment: Ah, OK. That interpretation of the question hadn't occurred to me but it seems entirely reasonable. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: Yes.

Not so short answer: It depends, since most bike computer sensors (The Reed switch / Hall sensor) are designed for a front fork - spoke clearance and usually this is smaller when compared with the chain/seat stays. I have done it when testing the maximum potential speed my gearing could achieve and had to add a rubber to act as an spacer, besides that everything else was virtually the same.

As long as you can keep it secured to avoid it getting trapped in the spokes/pedals it all should work smoothly.

Comment: You can't see it in the picture that I posted but I ended up using foam as a spacer, so you are absolutely correct. The spacing on the rear is way different than the fork.

Comment: Great! Just as an extra keeping the sensor as close as possible from the hub is a must in order to keep accuracy at it's max (Since the speed is lower the closer you get to it giving more time to respond). Foam has lower friction and I would prefer rubber on the move, but with an a trainer that'ts not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have just purchased and installed a B'Twin 500 "cyclometer" from Decathlon (AU$49).  It has a gyro device which attaches to the rear hub and communicates to the handlebar readout wirelessly.  The instructions are a bit difficult to follow but works well.  There are several reviews of this device on-line.  Worth checking out.

Answer (score -1):

decathlon actually sell a computer designed to use with the turbo trainers it has 2 sensors that fit on rear wheel and pedal arm. then you use app on you phone to get live display.